# Ooyala AS3 API strange issue

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, flash-builder

I have got a strange issue with Ooyala AS3 API.

Below code works perfect, I have got a requirement to remove adSetCode so when I remove `params['adSetCode'] = param.adSetCode;` from `ExternalInterface.addCallback` function and call

```
$("#player-id")[0].setQueryStringParameters({embedCode:id,links:url,autoplay:'1',adSetCode:asc, keywords:keys});
```

it works but only once. I can see the values being updated but video gets updated only first time?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
               xmlns:ooyala="com.ooyala.api.*">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.core.FlexGlobals;

            [Bindable]
            public var embedCode:String = 'FqcWJ4Mjpnzw0ZNH6aGE-CE6ZPKZReZp'; 
            [Bindable]
            public var adSetCode:String = 's2MzU6rIBpTe20SzgA_OahnRJMNZf_zJ';
            [Bindable]
            public var playerID:String = '';

            public var autoPlay:String = "false";

            public var keywords:String = ''; //inSkin keywords 

            public var params:Object = new Object(); 

            override protected function initializationComplete():void
            {
                super.initializationComplete();

                if(FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.parameters.embedCode != undefined) {
                    embedCode = FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.parameters.embedCode;
                }

                if(FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.parameters.adSetCode != undefined) {
                    adSetCode = FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.parameters.adSetCode;
                }

                if(FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.parameters.keywords != undefined) {
                    keywords = FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.parameters.keywords;
                }

                if(FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.parameters.autoplay != undefined) {
                    autoPlay = FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.parameters.autoplay;
                }

                player.load();

                ExternalInterface.addCallback("setQueryStringParameters", function(param:Object):void {
                    params['embedCode'] = param.embedCode;
                    params['adSetCode'] = param.adSetCode;
                    params['autoplay'] = param.autoplay;
                    keywords = param.keywords;

                    player.queryStringParameters = params; 
                })

                player.addEventListener("apiReady",function(event:Event):void {
                    main();
                }); 
            }

            public function main():void {

                if(autoPlay == "true") {
                    player.playMovie();
                } 

                var jsStr:String = player.embedCode+'^'+player.title; 
                keywords = removeNonNumericChars(keywords);

                //Add event listeners here for js
                player.addEventListener("stateChanged", function(event:Event):void {
                    try {
                        ExternalInterface.call("receiveOoyalaEvent", FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.parameters.id, event.type, player.state );
                    }
                    catch(e:ErrorEvent) {}  // just throwing this away as the function may or may not be there.
                });

                player.addEventListener("playheadTimeChanged", function(event:Event):void {
                    try {
                        ExternalInterface.call("receiveOoyalaEvent", FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.parameters.id, event.type, player.state );
                    }
                    catch(e:ErrorEvent) {}  
                });

                player.addEventListener("playComplete", function(event:Event):void {
                    try {
                        ExternalInterface.call("receiveOoyalaEvent", FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.parameters.id, event.type, player.state );
                    }
                    catch(e:ErrorEvent) {} 
                });

                player.addEventListener("adStarted", function(event:Event):void {
                    try {
                        ExternalInterface.call("receiveOoyalaEvent", FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.parameters.id, event.type, player.state );
                    }
                    catch(e:ErrorEvent) {}  
                });

                player.addEventListener("adCompleted",
                    function(event:Event):void {
                        try {
                            ExternalInterface.call("receiveOoyalaEvent", FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.parameters.id, event.type, player.state );
                        }
                        catch(e:ErrorEvent) {}  
                    });

                player.addEventListener("embedCodeChanged",
                    function(event:Event):void {
                        try {

                            ExternalInterface.call("receiveOoyalaEvent", FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.parameters.id, event.type, jsStr );
                        }
                        catch(e:ErrorEvent) {}  
                    });

                //Send play started event for tealium tracking on main
                try {
                    ExternalInterface.call("receiveOoyalaEvent", FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.parameters.id, 'PlayStarted', jsStr );
                    ExternalInterface.call("receiveOoyalaEvent", FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.parameters.id, 'inSkinKeywords', keywords );
                }
                catch(e:ErrorEvent) {}  // just throwing this away as the function may or may not be there.


                //Following events are for inskin implementation 
                player.addEventListener("apiReady",
                    function(event:Event):void {
                        try {

                            ExternalInterface.call("receiveOoyalaEvent", FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.parameters.id, event.type, '' );
                        }
                        catch(e:ErrorEvent) {}  
                    });

                player.addEventListener("currentItemEmbedCodeChanged",
                    function(event:Event):void {
                        try {

                            ExternalInterface.call("receiveOoyalaEvent", FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.parameters.id, event.type, jsStr + '^'
                                + player.description + '^' + player.totalTime + '^' + player.lineup );
                        }
                        catch(e:ErrorEvent) {}  
                    });

                player.addEventListener("fullscreenChanged",
                    function(event:Event):void {
                        try {

                            ExternalInterface.call("receiveOoyalaEvent", FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.parameters.id, event.type, player.fullscreen );
                        }
                        catch(e:ErrorEvent) {}  
                    });

                player.addEventListener("totalTimeChanged",
                    function(event:Event):void {
                        try {

                            ExternalInterface.call("receiveOoyalaEvent", FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.parameters.id, event.type, player.totalTime );
                        }
                        catch(e:ErrorEvent) {}  
                    });

                //Methods for inskin implementation 
                ExternalInterface.addCallback("inSkinPlay",Play);
                ExternalInterface.addCallback("inSkinPause",Pause);
                ExternalInterface.addCallback("getTotalTime",getTotalTime);
                ExternalInterface.addCallback("getInSkinKeywords",getInSkinKeywords);
            }

            private function Play():void
            {
                player.playMovie();
            }

            private function Pause():void
            {
                player.pauseMovie();    
            }

            private function getTotalTime():Number
            {
                return player.totalTime;
            }

            private function getInSkinKeywords():String
            {
                return keywords;
            }


            private function removeNonNumericChars($str:String):String {
                $str = $str.toLowerCase();
                $str = replaceAll($str, " ", "-")
                var newStr:String = "";
                for (var i:int = 0; i<$str.length; i++) {
                    var currentCharCode:Number = $str.charCodeAt(i);
                    if ((currentCharCode >= 48) && (currentCharCode <= 57) || (currentCharCode >= 97) && (currentCharCode <= 122) || (currentCharCode == 45) || (currentCharCode == 44)) {
                        newStr += $str.charAt(i);
                    }
                }
                return newStr;
            }

            private function replaceAll(str:String, fnd:String, rpl:String):String{
                return str.split(fnd).join(rpl);
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <fx:Declarations>   
        <fx:Object
            id = "defaultPlayerSettings"
            allowFullScreen = "true"
            autoplay = "false"
            embedCode = "{embedCode}"
            adSetCode = "{adSetCode}"
            />
    </fx:Declarations>

    <ooyala:Player
        id="player"
        width="100%" height="100%" 
        verticalCenter="0" horizontalCenter="0"
        queryStringParameters="{defaultPlayerSettings}"     
        />
</s:Application>
```